# AutoMod not reading correct word

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am attempting to add an automod cog to my discord bot. I have written a blacklist command and whitelist command in a different file and they work fine. What i can't figure out is when it loads the blacklisted words from the .csv file it loads them to the variable as ["['Test']"] and not as Test. If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know.

```
class AutoMod(commands.Cog):
def __init__ (self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.words = Words
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    self.words = {}
    with open(Wdir, 'r') as csv_file:
        csvreader=csv.reader(csv_file)
        for line in csvreader:
            Words.append(str(line))
    print(f'AutoMod {Words}')

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    print(Words)
    if str(Words) in message.content:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, You are not allowed to say that')
    else:
        pass
```

def setup(bot):
bot.add_cog(AutoMod(bot))

Answer (score 0):

You can do smth like this:

```
filtered_words = ["badword", "verybadword"]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     for word in filtered_words:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("This word is blacklisted")
       
            await client.process_commands(message)
```

Now bot will delete a message that contains any of filtered words. Bot will also send a message that says word is blacklisted.

Comment: This works fine and i know i can do this. The problem is when i import the words from a csv file it doesn't import correctly and instead requires you to add Quotation marks and Brackets to your message.